# Want to take a scss assoicated array and generate variables and classes from them

Tags: css, html, sass

This is primarily a syntax question, I'm pretty sure I can do this but I don't know the best way to unquote, declare variables, and concatenate strings in the for loop. Essentially though I want to take this map I made and generate the variables for the colors as well as some classes that will assign styles such as font-color and background-color.

```
$color-collection: ('white': '#FFFFFF', 'black': '#000000', 'goldenrod': '#F59600');
@for $i from 0 to length($color-collection) {


//create a variable for each color name, e.g. $white: #FFFFFF;
//create a class for each variable name with a style, e.g. .bg-color-white {background-color: $white;}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use `@each` instead of `@for`.

Second you can just get the two variables you need in the loop itself. The first variable will be the key, and the second the value.

Third we can use sass interpolation to include the variable in a class name and to unqote the value in a selector. I think you could also use `unqote($color-value)` for this, or you could just write your color values in the array without quotation-marks.

Se example below.

```
$color-collection: ('white': '#FFFFFF', 'black': '#000000', 'goldenrod': '#F59600');
@each $color-name, $color-value in $color-collection {

  .bg-color-#{$color-name} {
    background-color: #{$color-value};
  }
//create a variable for each color name, e.g. $white: #FFFFFF;
//create a class for each variable name with a style, e.g. .bg-color-white {background-color: $white;}

}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/e321b7e36ed0e74cd2ce

Since you are using libsass here's some code that would work with older Sass syntax:

```
$color-collection: ('white' '#FFFFFF'), ('black' '#000000'), ('goldenrod' '#F59600');
@each $color in $color-collection {
  $color-name: nth($color, 1);
  $color-value: nth($color, 2);
  .bg-color-#{$color-name} {
    background-color: #{$color-value};
  }
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/28caaf9d5e644d5db0cc

Comment: That looks promising but I get an array when I define the $color-collection variable. Perhaps my version of scss doesn't support that? How can I tell what version I'm using? I'm using "gulp-sass": "0.7.x" but I don't know what version of sass that corresponds to.

Comment: gulp-sass uses libsass which is much faster, but does not support assoicative arrays (yet). Much work is being done on libsass to get it to Sass 3.3 spec (which has these arrays), but for now they're aiming at 3.2. You could use "gulp-ruby-sass" which should work, but it can be quite a bit slower to render the css.

Comment: If you wanna keep using gulp-sass I've added some code that works with libsass